# Intuit (Quickbooks) API Upload Image as an attachable to an Item (product) NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, quickbooks

I'm using the Quickbooks API with the NodeJS SDK ([oauth-jsclient](https://github.com/intuit/oauth-jsclient/tree/master)) and I'm having issues trying to figure out how to upload an image to an Inventory Item. Per documentation [(docs)](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/attachable#upload-attachments)it says to make a multipart/form-data post request to the endpoint `https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/${company_id}/upload?minorversion=70`.

I'm doing all that and I'm also using the form-data library to handle the multipart/form-data to attach the image file. The issue I'm having is that I get an error response from the API saying `Content length missing in request","Detail":"We cannot find the content-length header in the request.","code":"6020"}`

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
try {
  if (images?.length) {
    const image = images[0];
    const imageFile = fs.createReadStream(image.rawInfo.path);
    
    const form = new FormData();

    form.append('file_content_01', imageFile, {
      filename: image.rawInfo.filename,
      contentType: image.rawInfo.mimetype,
    });

    form.append(
      'file_metadata_01',
      JSON.stringify({
        AttachableRef: [
          {
            EntityRef: { type: 'Item', value: newQBProduct.Id },
          },
        ],
        ContentType: image.rawInfo.mimetype,
        FileName: image.rawInfo.filename,
      }),
      {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        filename: 'file_metadata_01',
      }
    );
    
    console.log({ formHeader: form.getHeaders() });
    
    const imageResponse = await qbClient.makeApiCall({
      url: `${process.env.QB_API_URL}/v3/company/${process.env.QB_COMPANY_ID}/upload?minorversion=69`,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        ...form.getHeaders(),
      },
      body: form,
    });
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log({ ERROR_UPLOADING_IMAGE: error });
}
```

If I console log the headers this is what I get:

```
{
  formHeader: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------348255206805762341115729'
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out.

Its due to the lack of support in handling multipart/form data in the oauth-jsclient library. According to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/intuit/oauth-jsclient/issues/112)

Not clear if they added the support since then, but I'm guessing they haven't due to the error I'm getting.